# bootstrap input group with progress bar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to group a progress bar, "browse" button and a "upload" button in a single row using bootstrap input grouping. Im using bootstrap 4 and I tried following.

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02">
            <div class="custom-file-label">
              <div class="progress" style="height:40px">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" style="width: 25%"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Upload</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

but the styling goes wrong as below.

[image]

I want following output.

1. Progress bar should be same height as buttons.
2. Progress bar should be ended at the "browse" button and should not overlap.
3. Progress bar should be aligned to the "browse" button.

it should be as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two line of css can fix your problem

```
 .custom-file-label {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn{
    height:40px;
  }
  .progress{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 75%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .custom-file-label::after {
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution and this fix will align the progress bar with the buttons. But my 2nd issue is still exist as I mentioned in my post **(Progress bar should be ended at the "browse" button and should not overlap.)**. If you set the **aria-valuenow="95"** and **style="width: 95%"** in the progress bar, you will see the issue.

Comment: @Prabodha I have updated your issue please check. If it's work for you please upvote

Answer (score 1):

Please override the padding given by "custom-file-label" class.

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/maloth_n/kh9jm8do/1 for solution

Code:

```
<div class="form-group row m-2">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02" />
        <div class="custom-file-label">
          <div class="progress" style="height:40px">
            <div
              class="progress-bar"
              role="progressbar"
              aria-valuenow="25"
              style="width: 25%"
              aria-valuemin="0"
              aria-valuemax="100"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<style>
.custom-file-label {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the solution and this fix will align the progress bar with the buttons. But my 2nd issue is still exist as I mentioned in my post **(Progress bar should be ended at the "browse" button and should not overlap.)**. If you set the **aria-valuenow="95"** and **style="width: 95%"** in the progress bar, you will see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css rule:

```
  .form-group .custom-file-label {
        padding: 0;
    }

   button.btn.btn-outline-secondary {
      height: 40px;
      border-left: 0;
      border-color: #ccc;
   }
```

Add classes in HTML for respective elements and update CSS rules.

Comment: thank you for the solution and this fix will align the progress bar with the buttons. But my 2nd issue is still exist as I mentioned in my post **(Progress bar should be ended at the "browse" button and should not overlap.)**. If you set the **aria-valuenow="95"** and **style="width: 95%"** in the progress bar, you will see the issue.